# Access to last Value of Alias Field in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, alias, lag

i need to access to the prev alias field like this Sample.
i want to calculate A:

```
Select * , 
A = (b/c*LAG(A) Over (order by C))
from Tbl
```

Comment: You need to provide some details here. This is not at all clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You might try looking here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As it's currently written, we could just write `A=NULL` which isn't very interesting (since the value of `LAG()` for the first row will be `NULL` and `NULL`s propagate). Once we know what the right "root" condition is, it looks like this would be better  worked out with a recursive CTE. You'll get no benefit from trying to use `LAG` since we cannot determine the value for row `n` without having computed values for all other rows between `1` and `n-1`.